# Access to objects created outside of the reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm looking for the solution to get the object created in the parent namespace/environment when calling a function in reactive. This example simplifies the problem:

- I've created `object <- "x"` in the main frame of the shiny application and I would like to find and use this object inside of the function called in reactive.
  Limitations:
- The object can't be passed through using `foo(object = object)`.
- Object should not be written to the `session$userData`
- Object should not be written to .globalEnv as this can be a module (one of multiple) and they should have a separate `object` object.

```r
foo <- function() {
  # how to obtain the object from the server namespace? 
  # browser()
  object
}


app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = "example",
    uiOutput(outputId = "example")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    object <- "x"
    
    some_reactive <- reactive({
      foo()
    })
    
    output$example <- renderUI(some_reactive())
  }
)

runApp(app)
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Purely out of curiosity: Where do those limitations come from?

Comment: Application initialize some specific singleton object and we are using some functions which automatically refers to this obeject. Currently we have this singleton in `session` but it brings the problem with passing it to the other modules.

Comment: Another limitation added.. deleting my answer ;-)

Comment: @ismirsehregal thanks for the first effort anyway!

Comment: Depending on the respond from the community here. I guess at the end I will do as you said - open possibility to pass the object instead of "environment surfing".

Answer (score 2):

The solution is about juggling parent's environment level, but I'm not sure this is what you are looking for:

```
library(shiny)

foo <- function() {
  # how to obtain the object from the server namespace?
  # browser()
  get(x = "object", envir = parent.frame(1))
}


app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = "example",
    uiOutput(outputId = "example")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    object <- "x"
    custom_env <- environment()
    custom_env$object <- object

    some_reactive <- reactive({
      do.call(what = foo, args = list(), envir = custom_env)
    })

    output$example <- renderUI(some_reactive())
  }
)

runApp(app)
```

EDIT:

This one also works and is bit simpler:

```
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = "example",
    uiOutput(outputId = "example")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    custom_env <- environment()
    object <- "x"
    custom_env$object <- object

    some_reactive <- reactive(env = custom_env, {
      foo()
    })

    output$example <- renderUI(some_reactive())
  }
)
```